# Adding all the fields of layer to another using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, fields-attributes

I try to add all the fields of layer X to layer Y. This is my code:

```py
layerX = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layername1")    
layerY = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layername2") 

#read field name and type of layerX
fields = [ field.name() for field in layerX.fields() ] #list of all fields
fieldtype = [ field.typeName() for field in layerX.fields() ] #list of all fieldtypes

#add fields to layerY
i = 0
for f in fields:

####### Not part of my question from here....
#it's only about breaking (because I don't take field[0] which is the ID) and changing "Integer" to "Int"
      
    i = i + 1
    laenge = len(fields)
    if i == laenge: 
        break
    feldname = fields[i]
    if fieldtype[i] == "Integer":
        feldtyp = "Int"
    else:
        feldtyp = fieldtype[i]
####### Not part of my question .... to here

    qvaria = "QVariant."+feldtyp
    layerY.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(feldname, QVariant.String)])  #WORKS
    layerY.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(feldname, qvaria)])  #DOES NOT WORK
```

It works perfectly if I type `QVariant.String` or `QVariant.Int` in the last function. If I autogenerate the same statement (using `qvaria` instead of `QVariant.String`), it returns the following error:

> `QgsField()`: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
> #overload 1: argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
> #overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Do you know how I can make my script run?
Is there an easier way to add all the fields from one to another layer?

Comment: `qvaria` is a vairable containing a string, `QVariant.String` is a type constant that QPygis understands - they are very different so it will never work this way.

Comment: Why not `layerY.dataProvider().addAttributes(layerX.fields())` ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo: I don't know. When I enter this code, it says "False". Maybe I have to make sure, it doesn't want to generate an other ID?

Comment: @IanTurton: Thanks for the clarification. I just hoped that it would read the string and since it is exactly the same as if I enter it manually, it would work?

Comment: If you want types : `[field.type() for field in layerX.fields()]`

Comment: @J.Monticolo: I tried your second suggestion. This would be really short and nice! It returns following error: "AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'addProvider'"
And yes, the added fields sould be the same type as the ones in the original point-feature. 

could it be that there is a problem adding boolean, real and date types with this method?

Comment: `dataProdiver` ! So : `layerY.dataProvider().addAttributes([field for field in layerX.fields() if field.name() not in ["id"]])`

Comment: @J.Monticolo: thanks a lot! That's the perfect solution and even very short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layerX = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layername1")    
layerY = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layername2") 
layerY.dataProvider().addAttributes([field for field in layerX.fields() if field.name() not in ["fid"]])
```

No iteration needed.

Comment: Don't forget `layerY.updateFields()` in the end.